# Firebase App Check - Can You Turn Off "Enforce" Action

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check

I couldn't find a direct answer in the documentation. I'm assuming this is true, but can we reverse an "Enforce" action if there are scenarios in which we need to shut it off?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebaser here!

You can always disable enforcement of App Check, although it may take a few minutes for the changes to take effect.

Please note that enforcement will only affect Firebase managed backends such as Cloud Storage for Firebase and Cloud Firestore.  For Cloud Functions or other backends which run custom enforcement logic you will need to make those changes yourself and deploy them.

Once you enforce it will looks something like this:
[image]

Comment: how come 50% are unverfied?

Comment: this is a sample screenshot from a test project, traffic was generated using a script and is not an accurate representation of a real app with organic traffic, I was mostly using to demonstrate the button state.