# How can I unregister from Firebase Appcheck App Attest?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-app-check

I've registered my unity app to App Attest in App Check firebase console. Then I saw that app check is not available for unity projects yet. Now I have to unregister my app from it, how can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean that you *enabled enforcement*? If so, you can **unenforce** that in the console too. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72736251/firebase-app-check-can-you-turn-off-enforce-action

Comment: No, I haven't enforced just registered for the ios app check. But I couldn't find how to disable and I wonder, Are the unverified database requests are restricted from now on? Because there are shown on monitor app check page.

Comment: Just enabling App Check for a project doesn't do enforce anything yet, so is a harmless operation. As long as you don't enforce it, there is not need to roll it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've enabled App Check for your project, but are not actually enforcing it yet. There is no way to roll this initial operation back, but since it doesn't actually affect the functioning of your apps yet that should not lead to any problems.